# форма для поиска с acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems, route

Использую гем acts-as-taggable-on для добавления тегов к постам. Не получается составить форму для поиска постов с тегом.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
    }

    resources :posts
    resources :users, except: [:destroy, :update, :create, :new, :edit] do
        member do
            get :following, :followers
        end
    end
    resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

    get 'my_posts' => 'users#my_posts', as: 'my_posts'
    get 'tags/:tag_list' => 'posts#index', as: :tags

    root 'posts#index'
end
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
...
    def index
        if params[:tag_list]
            @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag_list], parse: true, :any => true).paginate(page: params[:page]).includes(:user).order('created_at DESC')
        else
            @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page]).includes(:user).order('created_at DESC')
        end
    end
...
```

rake routes :

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               users/registrations#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
          following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format) users#following
          followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format) users#followers
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
           relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)       relationships#create
            relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)   relationships#destroy
                my_posts GET    /my_posts(.:format)            users#my_posts
                    tags GET    /tags/:tag_list(.:format)      posts#index
                    root GET    /                              posts#index
```

при выводе постов, я генерирую теги таким образом:

```
<% post.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag, tags_path(tag) %>
<% end %>
```

это создает ссылки вида `<a href="/tags/blabla">blabla</a>`, при нажатии на которые поиск срабатывает корректно.
Но когда я пытаюсь сгенерировать отдельную форму для такого поиска, вылезает ошибка несоответствия маршрута.

```
<%= form_tag("/tags", method: "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:tag_list) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

При нажатии кнопки формируется такой url `http://127.0.0.1:3000/tags?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tag_list=taxi&commit=Search` и ошибка

> No route matches [GET] "/tags"

если я в `routes.rb` убираю `:tag_list`, то поиск по форме работает, но перестает работать поиск по ссылкам.

Как правильно сгенерировать эту форму?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось так:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "posts", action: "index"}, method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:tag_list) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```